# how clustering in tomcat actually works

Tags: tomcat

I was going through the tomcat  clustering documentation.

I would like to know how a tomcat node finds other tomcat nodes. All the tomcats would be starting up in different machines and could be in different ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding of the documentation [cluster information](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/cluster-howto.html#Cluster_Information) is exchanged using multicast IP addresses.
Each server is listening on and sending heartbeats to a common multicast address (228.0.0.4 by default). The heartbeat contains the servers' IP address and listening port.

For example server `A` starts up and sends a hartbeat containing '192.168.17.3:4012' to the common multicast address 228.0.0.4.
Servers `B`, `C` and `D` now know how to communicate with server `A`.
Servers `B`, `C` and `D` also send heartbeats periodically, thus server `A` soon knows how to communicate to each of them.

Comment: Thank you. That has made it very clear. I was not familiar with the concept of multicasting and how a multicast ip works.